# Insert ignore alternative for sybase IQ

Tags: sql, database, sap-iq

What is the alternative for **Insert ignore** in sybase IQ.

I want inserts to go through without failing in case of duplicates , and insert all the non-duplicates. The table has a unique key constraint on a column

Answer (score 1):

Try the `on existing skip` clause:

```
insert into mytable (col1, col2) 
   on existing skip 
   values ('a','b')
```

Comment: What version of IQ are you using?

Comment: version used is sybase IQ 15.